# Is there a port list migration command set for FreeBSD?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, bsd-ports, migration

On debianized linux distros there is `dpkg --get-selections`, `dpkg --set-selections`, `dpkg -C` to respectively list installed packages, select a list of packages for installations, and list packages that are in a partially installed or broken state.  I am wondering if something like this exists for FreeBSD (ports, not packages).  I can get the list from `pkg_info`, but is there a simple way to apply it without `cut`, `for port in list`, `cd`, `make install`?

Comment: When you ask this kind of questions, you should describe what the commands you're used to do (like I've done). Otherwise only people who know both systems have a chance to answer. This way someone who only knows FreeBSD has a chance.

Comment: Sorry Gilles.  I haven't probed too deeply into this one(still a FreeBSD n00b, although I do have gnome/flash on native firefox/general multimedia working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portmaster&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) has example how to do bulk port re-install.

Comment: Thanks.  I was using portsnap/portupgrade/portaudit.  I hadn't looked into portmaster.  The relevant example/switch was --list-origins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with portupgrade, "portupgrade --all" will upgrade all ports that have newer versions available.  The "--force" flag can be used to force a re-install or downgrade of a specified port if you know it's broken.

You can get a list of the current versions of your installed ports and whether newer versions are available in your ports tree with "portversion --fullname --verbose".

I don't know of a tool that automatically detects partially installed ports.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I was looking for a batch install type of thing for installing all currently installed packages on another clean box.  AlexD had what I was looking for covered.